# Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in CodeIgnitor

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I am returning more than one value in the model so I did like

```
return array('true' =>1,'customer_id' => $result->customer_id);
```

and In the controller, I am displaying like

```
$true=$result['true'];
$custId=$result['customer_id'];
```

So there is no issue in this.

Now let's talk about in details

In the model, I have this logic

```
//sql query
if ($result) {
    if ($result->password_change == 0) {
         return array('true' =>1,'customer_id' => $result->customer_id);//multiple returns
    }
    else{
       return $result;
    }
}
else{return false;}
```

In the controller

```
 $result=$this->Member_model->check_data(parameters);
 $true=$result['true'];
 $custId=$result['customer_id'];

 if ($result) {
     if($true == 1){
         //some code here
     }
     else{
         //some code here
     }
 }
 else{
 }
```

This is my second code.

```
if ($result) {
  if ($result - > password_change == 0) {
    if ($result - > id == $id) {
      return array('true' => 1, 'customer_id' => $result - > customer_id); //return more then 2
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if ()) // some condition
  {
    return (array) $result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
} else {
  return false;
}
```

I am getting the error that

> "Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Because when returning if condition(from the model) then it's working but when it returns else (I mean $result from the model) then I am getting the error because it is not getting the $result['true'].

Hope you can understand my issue. Would you help me out on this issue?

Comment: Well you need to accommodate the different return permutations in your controller. You are currently just assuming the return value is the array you're creating.

Comment: @Utkanos, Can you explain me with the help of an example? Please

Comment: It's like this. Your model is returning different types of data, but your controller is not checking for this - it's assuming only one of those types. So either harmonise your model to always return a given type of data, or tell your controller to first CHECK the type of returned data before proceeding. See @Richard Parnaby-King's answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either: ALWAYS return an array, or return an ArrayObject:

#### Alway return an Array

In your else, cast `$result` as an array:

```
//sql query
if ($result) {
    if ($result->password_change == 0) {
         return array('true' =>1,'customer_id' => $result->customer_id);//multiple returns
    }
    return (array) $result;
}
return false;
```

#### Always return an ArrayObject

Not knowing if this model is returning the result anywhere else in you application, I have no idea if other code expects `$result` to be an object. Casting as an array might break your code elsewhere. Let's convert `$result` from `stdClass` to an `ArrayObject`:

```
//sql query
if ($result) {
    if ($result->password_change == 0) {
         return array('true' =>1,'customer_id' => $result->customer_id);//multiple returns
    }
    return new \ArrayObject($result, \ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
}
return false;
```

This approach will allow you to call `$result['test']` AND `$result->test`.

Comment: One little issue in the case where it returns false which is boolean so the controller needs to test $result before trying to extract either arrays or objects...

Comment: @Richard, Give me some time to check.

Comment: I just want to know why you removed the else condition? because I have 2 more conditions in the else. I am still getting the error Message: Undefined index: true

Comment: Sorry, that's my personal ocd. There's nothing wrong leaving them in :)

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King, Wait a min, I am updating my code in the question for more clarity.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King, I added code in the question. Kindly check the last code. I mean check "This is my second code." I am getting the error Undefined index: true

Answer (score 1):

```
Yeah, ok this is solution for multiple conditions : 

    $this->db->select('*'); // Here your column name
    $this->db->from('members'); // Table name
    $this->db->where($login_access); // Here your condition
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result_array();
    $query = $this->db->get('customer'); // Your code above if condition
    $result = $query->result_array(); // Get data in array Format using **result_array()**
        if ($result) {
          if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { // You have to change condition from **$result['password_change ']** To **$query->num_rows() > 0**
            if ($result - > id == $id) { // Also change here condition from **$result - > id** To $result['id']
              return array('true' => 1, 'customer_id' => $result['customer_id']); //Also change here from **$result - > customer_id** To $result['customer_id']
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          } else {
            if () // some condition
          {
            return $result; // Also Change here from **return (array) $result** To $result
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the else condition because I have more condition inside it.

Comment: @user9437856 by mistake I posted another answer. You can find it in this updated answer.

Comment: I am getting the error in this like if ($result['password_change'] == 0) { //Message: Undefined index: password_change

Comment: ook let me check i will give you solution in as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer again. You used  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {  May I know why you used that? I am fetching all the records and there is one column which is "password_change" and I am checking that column only.